# Add language directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I've been reading through most of the other .htaccess questions, and tried different solutions on my .htaccess file but with no success.

Here's the thing: I have a website (based on CodeIgniter) that already has a good SEO positioning. Now, the customer wants it translated to another language, but I dont want to lose that SEO so I thought of redirecting a URL like http://www.domain.com/contactUs to http://www.domain.com/en/contactUs, being (en) the current positioned language. CI would handle the other language as usual without problem. Im currently doing tests on localhost, so the following rules will have only "domain" instead of "domain.com".

I've tried these Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond ^(.*)/domain/(.*) !^/en/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/domain/(.*)$ $1/domain/en/$2
```

I want the RewriteCond to filter URLs coming in the new language so that the RewriteRule is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi ThinkingMonkey, thanks for answering. I've tried your solution but i get this error "The requested URL /en/contactUs.php was not found on this server." Of course, I do have that directory and file created. On top of that, the Cond fails to check if /en/ is on the URL, because it shows an error with /en/en/contactUs.php . If I edit the Rule and put the whole URI (RewriteRule ^(.*)$ localhost/domain/en/$1 [L])I get an Internal server error. Any thoughts?

Comment: still getting not found error. Seems it is not the RewriteBase's fault. Perhaps testing it on localhost has something to do with it, I'm gonna try and see if it works on the domain, and I'll let you know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ikerjer The rules were written based on this URL `http://www.domain.com/contactUs` . Is your `en` folder within folder named `domain`? do you have any other rewrite rules?

Comment: Not exactly ThinkingMonkey. CodeIgniter uses virtual directories to handle language redirections, and thus it does not meet your requirements. Nonetheless, I tried on another site and specifically created the structure you mention and still didn't work. Anyway, I am in a big hurry and I found how to write almost in a automatized way the redirections manually in the htaccess file, cant wait to find the right Rule :/. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your text in unique language files, then load them like so:

```
$this->config->set_item('language',"your_language");
$this->lang->load('default', "your_language");
```

To write out the content, the use:

```
$this->lang->line('message_id');
```

More info:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

This should more efficient than creating a duplicate site while still being SEO friendly.  In fact, it should be more SEO friendly.

Comment: Hi Jahmic, thank you for your answer. The thing is I do not have duplicate files in my site, I already use this CI library http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n. I wanted to use htaccess to preserve the natural positioning that the content has acquired without the /en/ and at the same time introduce a new language with CI's structure.

Comment: Rather late reply...  The approach I suggested doesn't need a /en/ segment either.  I've implemented this many times, with a language toggle for the user stored into a session variable.  In any case, I haven't looked into maestric, but it could be promising also.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond $2 !^en/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/domain/(.*)$ $1/domain/en/$2
```